# Angular - click event on select option element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my Angular 4 application I am using a select element. On a click on a option in the select element I want to open a dialog. However, I can't find a solution how to query if the option got clicked. I just have one option in the select, so I cannot query if the value changed because the value cannot change.

Is there any possibility to have a click event in the option element?

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: *ngFor with index? Load your index `let object = this.objectList[i]` into the dialog.

Answer (score 11):

You can't listen to click events of `<option>`.

You can use

```
<select ngModel (ngModelChange)="mySelectHandler($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let value of options" [ngValue]="value">{{value.text}}</option>
</select>
```

to execute code after an option was selected.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a disabled option so you can use change event, for example like this :

```
<select #selectList (change)="setValue(selectList.value)">
                      <option value="null" disabled>Select a Value</option>
                      <option  *ngFor="let o of Options" value="{{ o | json }}">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<nz-select <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
  ngModel="bank"
  nzAllowClear
  nzPlaceHolder="Select Bank"
  (ngModelclick)="onSelectedBank($event)"
  >
  <nz-option *ngFor="let bank of bankList" nzValue="{{ bank.id }}" nzLabel="{{ bank.bank_name }}"></nz-option>
</nz-select>
```